# Clang exception capturing not working correctly

Tags: c++, macos, exception, casting, clang

I'm using the clang x64 compiler on MacOS 10.12. I have the following code:

```
try {
    throw CryptoPP::Exception(CryptoPP::Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "test");
} catch(CryptoPP::Exception &e) {
    std::cout << "cryptopp" << e.what() << std::endl;
} catch(std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "std" << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The CryptoPP is build as static library. When I use it in in a executable application, it works as expected.

It gets problematic when I use the CryptoPP static library in a dynamic library. **Inside** the library, I have that exact code (i.e. the exception does not leave the library). However, the log shows

```
std test
```

Meaning that only the *second* catch did actually catch the exception. How is that possible?

Comment: I vaguely remember that this kind of problem comes up because the dynamic library doesn't have type information for the exception type.

Comment: That sounds like a lead. Do you have any references to continue reading on that problem?